# Composer REST server authentication

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to start composer-rest-server with multiuser property. But for this I need to setup authentication. I just find an example of auth by github passport strategy.

So my question is: is it possible, and if yes how, to setup my custom passport strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per our docs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html - Hyperledger Composer supports the passport strategies available here -> http://passportjs.org/ - see also these useful Rocketchat threads https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=KW4DbESMZKkPRWmPQ (from aneb) and here -> https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=uruWP9jJbCEQcQqNo (from 'anna') about custom passport strategies.